# How to correctly implement iteratively reweighted least squares algorithm for multiple logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, irls

I'm confused about the iteratively reweighted least squares algorithm used to solve for logistic regression coefficients as described on page 121 of *The Elements of Statistical Learning, 2nd Edition* (Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman 2009).

The final step of the process, after fitting a Taylor approximation to the log-likelihood of $N$ observations, is to solve the following weighted least squares problem:

$\beta^{new}\leftarrow argmin_{\beta}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)^T\textbf{W}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)$ $(1)$

by finding $\frac{\delta[(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)^T\textbf{W}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)]}{\delta\beta_j}$, setting $\frac{\delta[(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)^T\textbf{W}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)]}{\delta\beta_j}=0$, then solving for $\beta_j^{new}$,

where:

$\textbf{z}=\textbf{X}\beta^{old}+\textbf{W}^{-1}(\textbf{y}-\textbf{p})$,

$\textbf{W}=N\times{}N$ diagonal matrix of weights with $i$th diagonal element $p(x_i;\beta^{old})(1-p(x_i;\beta^{old}))$,

$\textbf{p}=$vector of fitted probabilities with $i$th element $p(x_i;\beta^{old})$,

$\textbf{y}=$vector of $y_i$ values,

$\textbf{X}=$matrix of $x_i$ values,

$\beta=$vector of coefficients $\beta_0,\beta_1,...,\beta_p$.

In the right hand part of expression (1), the $\beta$s are missing any superscript. Is $\beta$ presumed to be equal to $\beta^{old}$? That is, in order to solve for $\beta_j^{new}$ in (1) do we plug in the most current update of $\beta$ for all values of $\beta_{l\neq j}$ calculated in prior steps?

Comment: Just a word of caution: While the algorithms outlined in *ESL* are generally ok from a descriptive standpoint, **please** don't rely on anything in there being numerically stable or robust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an expression like

$$
\beta^{new}\leftarrow \text{argmin}_{b}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}b)^T\textbf{W}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}b)
$$

the point is that the output, $\beta^{new}$, is the result of considering all possible $b\in \mathbb{R}^p$ or whatever other space you are optimizing over. That's why there's no superscript: in the optimization problem $\beta$ is a dummy variable, just like with an integral (and I'm deliberately writing $b$ not $\beta$ to reflect $b$ being a dummy variable, not the target parameter).

The overall procedure involves getting a $\beta^{(t)}$, computing the "response" for the WLS, and then solving the WLS problem for $\beta^{(t+1)}$; as you know, we can use derivatives to get a nice closed-form solution for the optimal $\hat \beta$ for this problem. Thus $\beta^{old}$, which is fixed, appears in the vector $\textbf{z}$ in the WLS computation and then leads to $\beta^{new}$. That's the "iteration" part, that we use our current solution to create a new response vector; the WLS part then is solving for the new $\hat \beta$ vector. We keep doing this until there's no "significant" change.

Remember that the WLS procedure doesn't know that it is being used iteratively; as far as it is concerned, it is presented with an $X$, $y$, and $W$ and then outputs

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^T W X)^{-1} X^T W y
$$
like it would do in any other instance. We are being clever with our choice of $y$ and $W$ and iterating.

Update:
We can derive the solution to the WLS problem without using any component-wise derivatives. Note that if $Y \sim \mathcal N(X\beta, I)$ then $W^{1/2}Y \sim \mathcal N(W^{1/2}X\beta, W)$ from which we have that 
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text d\beta}\|W^{1/2}Y - W^{1/2}X\beta\|^2 = -2X^TWY + 2X^TWX\beta.
$$

Setting the derivative equal to 0 and solving we obtain

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TWX)^{-1} X^TWY.
$$

Thus for any inputs $W$, $X$, and $Y$ (provided W is positive definite and $X$ is full column rank) we get our optimal $\hat{\beta}$. It doesn't matter what these inputs are. So what we do is we use our $\beta^{old}$ to create our $Y$ vector and then we plug *that* in to this formula which outputs the optimal $\hat \beta$ for the given inputs. The whole point of the WLS procedure is to solve for $\hat \beta$. It in and of itself doesn't require plugging in a $\hat \beta$.

Comment: -Thank you for the explanation. I understand that the $\beta$s are dummy variables in the sense that $\beta_{l\neq j}$s are treated as constants when finding the derivative $\frac{\delta[(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)^T\textbf{W}(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X} \beta)]}{\delta\beta_j}$. However the solution to the derivative is going to be something like $2(\textbf{z}-\textbf{X}\beta)\textbf{W}\textbf{x}_j^T$. We're still left with a $\beta$ vector in the expression when solving for $\beta_j$ in the current iteration. Do we just plug in $\beta=\beta^{old}$?

Comment: I've updated the answer to try to address your comment.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. When solving for the logistic regression coefficients, we substite $\textbf{z}$ for $\textbf{y}$ giving us: $\hat{\beta} = (X^TWX)^{-1} X^TW \textbf{z}$ where $\textbf{z}=\textbf{X}\beta^{old}+\textbf{W}^{-1}(\textbf{y}-\textbf{p})$. The $argmin$ expression is really more of a shorthand, is that correct?

Comment: Just to be clear, with what you're doing, $y$ is your actual response data where $z$ is the "response" as used in the WLS formulas (sometimes $z$ is called the working response) which is what the $Y$ in my answers refers to. The argmin comes from the fact that regression is a minimization problem: we find $\beta$ to minimize the residual sum of squares. That's why we can set derivatives equal to 0, because we're looking for a minimum. The argmin notation is a very convenient way to express this.

Comment: That's correct, when applying IRLS to a logistic regression, I'm assuming $\textbf{y}$ is the response vector of 0s and 1s.

Comment: @jld The identity you applied to find the solution for the WLS problem assumes $W$ to be a constant diagonal matrix, isn't it supposed to be a function of theta?

Comment: @Essam this algorithm is iterative so $W$ uses $\beta^{\text{old}}$ which is treated as constant when $\beta^{\text{new}}$ is searched for

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.